# How to find examples of non-unique euclidean division in $\Bbb Z[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, euclidean-algorithm

The euclidean division of $1+8i$ by $2-4i$ can be one of two things:

$$1+8i=(2-4i)(i-1)-1+2i\tag{1}$$ $$\underbrace{1+8i}_\text{a}=\underbrace{(2-4i)}_\text{b}(\underbrace{-2+i}_\text{q})+\underbrace{1-2i}_\text{r}\tag{2}$$

And we have that $N(r)<N(b)$ where $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$ and the $b$'s aren't associated so those are really two different euclid divisions. (do the $r$'s have to be associated? here one is $(-1)$ times the other...)

What's the mindset in which we have to be to look for and find such examples?

Comment: The $r$'s must be associates. To construct more examples, take your favorite $r,$ let $b$ be any associate of $2r,$ take your favorite $q,$ finally calculate $a $ from $a = b q + r.$

Answer (score 3):

You even have non-unique Euclidean division in the integers. Dividing $9$ by $4$ could be either:

$$ 9 = 4 \cdot 2 + 1 $$
$$ 9 = 4 \cdot 3 + (-3) $$

You pretty much always have these examples, except for the special case that the remainder is zero. In cases like $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, given any one quotient-remainder pair, you can find others by adjusting the quotient by testing out the other numbers near the quotient.

I don't recall for sure how this all works out, but I think for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, that on average you should expect there to be $\pi$ different remainders satisfying $N(r) < N(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD, i.e. a unique factorisation domain. Therefore, whatever elements from $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we divide, the factorisation is unique. Also, if you may be interested: wikipedia says that $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}]$ is a unique factorisation domain for all $1\leqslant n \leqslant 22$ and not for $n=23$ (strange, isn't it?). We can compute $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ by taking $n=4$ (write exponent as cosine and sine). BTW, all euclidean domain are UFD's.

Comment: This is all true, but does not answer the question. Factorization is unique, but there are several ways to use the Euclidean algorithm to get to the greatest common divisors.

Comment: The simple answer is then that in a UFD two elements have **a** gcd. It may not be unique. Just take non-unit elements.

Comment: The question is about using different quotient/remainder pairs on the way to a gcd, not on the uniqueness (up to units) of the gcd.